# Concept connections on background in mindmap with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I'm trying to draw a mindmap with TikZ.

When drawing the concept connections, some of them cover the nodes themselves. Is there a direct way to force the connections to be on the background?

MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=150},
extra concept/.append style={color=blue!50,text=black}]

\begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=red!80, text=white]
\node [concept] (root) at (0,0) {root}[clockwise from=0]
   child[concept]
   {node [concept] (node-a) {A}
   }
   child[concept]
   {node [concept] (node-b) {B}
   }
 ;
\end{scope}

\draw [concept connection]
  (node-a) edge (node-b)
  ;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `backgrounds` library to your `tikzlibrary` and then enclose the connections in these tags:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background} <connections> \end{pgfonlayer}
```

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=150},
extra concept/.append style={color=blue!50,text=black}]

\begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=red!80, text=white]
\node [concept] (root) at (0,0) {root}[clockwise from=0]
   child[concept]
   {node [concept] (node-a) {A}
   }
   child[concept]
   {node [concept] (node-b) {B}
   }
 ;
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw [concept connection]
  (node-a) edge (node-b)
  ;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```